# When running my Java code System.out.println() doesn't recognize a condition

Tags: java, printing, filter, system, out

I'm trying to run this java code:

```
public class Lector{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numVentaint;
            try{         
                List<Guardar> guardar = new ArrayList<Guardar>();
                CsvReader ventas_import = new CsvReader("C:\\Users\\Karen Jaure\\Downloads\\Kubii-Sushi-Ventas.csv"); // ac· se agrega la ruta de csv
                ventas_import.readHeaders();
                    while (ventas_import.readRecord()){
                        String numVenta= ventas_import.get(0);
                        String fechaVenta= ventas_import.get(1);
                        String horaVenta= ventas_import.get(2);
                        String nombreProducto = ventas_import.get(4);
                        String montoTotal= ventas_import.get(7);
                        String codProducto= ventas_import.get(3);
                        String precioUnitarioProducto= ventas_import.get(5);
                        String cantidadUnidades = ventas_import.get(6);       
                        guardar.add(new Guardar(numVenta, fechaVenta, horaVenta, codProducto, nombreProducto, precioUnitarioProducto, cantidadUnidades));    
                    }
                ventas_import.close();
                    for(Guardar us:guardar){         
                        System.out.println(us.getNumVenta());
                    }     
                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }     
}
```

I want to show only "numVenta" attribute of "Guardar" class but when I run it, the system out print method doesn't filter the attribute given by the "Guardar" class method ".getNumVenta()".
I just can't find the error! Help will be very appreciated.

*UPDATED*
Here is the "Guardar" class:

```
public class Guardar {
   private String numVenta;
   private String fechaVenta;
   private String horaVenta;
   private String codProducto;
   private String nomProducto;
   private String precioUnitario;
   private String cantidadUnidades;

    public Guardar(String numVenta, String fechaVenta, String horaVenta, String codProducto, String nomProducto, String precioUnitario, String cantidadUnidades) {
        this.numVenta = numVenta;
        this.fechaVenta = fechaVenta;
        this.horaVenta = horaVenta;
        this.codProducto = codProducto;
        this.nomProducto = nomProducto;
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
        this.cantidadUnidades = cantidadUnidades;
    }

    public String getNumVenta() {
        return numVenta;
    }

    public void setNumVenta(String numVenta) {
        this.numVenta = numVenta;
    }

    public String getFechaVenta() {
        return fechaVenta;
    }

    public void setFechaVenta(String fechaVenta) {
        this.fechaVenta = fechaVenta;
    }

    public String getHoraVenta() {
        return horaVenta;
    }

    public void setHoraVenta(String horaVenta) {
        this.horaVenta = horaVenta;
    }

    public String getCodProducto() {
        return codProducto;
    }

    public void setCodProducto(String codProducto) {
        this.codProducto = codProducto;
    }

    public String getNomProducto() {
        return nomProducto;
    }

    public void setNomProducto(String nomProducto) {
        this.nomProducto = nomProducto;
    }

    public String getPrecioUnitario() {
        return precioUnitario;
    }

    public void setPrecioUnitario(String precioUnitario) {
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
    }

    public String getCantidadUnidades() {
        return cantidadUnidades;
    }

    public void setCantidadUnidades(String cantidadUnidades) {
        this.cantidadUnidades = cantidadUnidades;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please post your Guardar class?

Comment: What is being printed out?

Comment: Perhaps the configured delimiters of your CsvReader class do not match the delimeters in the CSV file, so all the data is parsed as being in the first column.